# Socket Programming - Java - Not receiving some messages

Tags: java, network-programming, serversocket

I just started working on Sockets with both client and server threads in the same Node. Below is my code structure -

I have a Node class which makes connections to different Nodes. It sends REQUEST messages to the Nodes and waits till it gets REPLY from all the nodes tracked using the outstandingreplies variable which is static and volatile, also has synchronised getters and setters.

Server Class spawns Processor thread which processes each message that it hears.
It modifies certain variables which furthers the code execution. On getting a REPLY message, it decrements outstandingreplies variable. It also sends messages to node which just sent the messages based on certain conditions.

Below is my code, I have removed certain details.

Node Class

```
    // Creates connections to other Nodes(machines) and sends messages
    public class Node {

      public static volatile int timestamp = 0;
  public static volatile int highestTimestamp = 0;
  public static int csCounter = 0;
  public static int nodeId;
  public static int n;
  public static String[] hosts;
  public static int[] ports;
  public static volatile int[] deferredNodes;
  public static volatile boolean requestingCS = false;
  public static volatile int outstandingReplies;

      // skipping getters and setters for variables shared between server and client threads

      // method to connect the node with other nodes
      public static Connection connect() {
      // skipping standar code to create sockets 
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {

        // start the receiver
        Server server = new Server();
        server.start();

        // make the connections with other nodes
        Connection connections = connect();

        while (counter <= 2) {

          // create a message
          Message message = new Message(); // skipping details to create a msg

          // send requests to all other nodes
          for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (i != nodeId) {
              System.out.println("Sending message " + message + " to node " + i);
              try {
                connections.outs[i].writeObject(message);
                outstandingReplies++;
              } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
            }
          }

          // All REQUEST messages sent, WAIT for all replies
          while (outstandingReplies != 0) {
            // System.out.println("Waiting for replies");
          }

          // send REPLY msg based on some logic         
          if(logic is true){  
          // send messages to other nodes
              Message replyMessage = new Message("REPLY", timestamp, nodeId);
              try {
                connections.outs[i].writeObject(replyMessage);
              } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
            }
        }


Connections Class
// Stores all the connections created by the Node Class

Server Class
// Listens to requests from nodesand spawns a Processor thread for each socket

    public class Server extends Thread {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          System.out.println("Starting the node's receiver thread");
          // create a serversocket to listen to requests
          ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Node.ports[Node.nodeId]);

          for (int i = 0; i < Node.n - 1; i++) {
            System.out.println("Opening sockets");
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            // create a processor thread for each to read and process the incoming Messages
            Processor processor = new Processor(socket);
            System.out.println("Starting message processor");
            processor.start();
          }
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

    Processor Class
    // Processes the messages and sends reply when needed

public class Processor extends Thread {

  Socket socket;
  int[] replies = new int[10];

  public Processor(Socket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
      ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(
          socket.getOutputStream());

      while (true) {
        System.out.println("Waiting for msg");
        System.out.println("Socket is " + socket.isConnected());
        Message message = (Message) in.readObject();
        Node.timestamp = Math.max(Node.timestamp + 1, message.timestamp);

        // printing the queue here
        System.out.println("Processor received " + message);

        // if message is a request
        if (message.type.trim().equals("REQUEST")) {

            if(condition is true){
             // do something
            } else {
             // send reply to node who sent you message
              Message replyMessage = new Message("REPLY", Node.timestamp,
                  Node.nodeId);
              System.out.println(
                  "Send " + replyMessage + " to " + Node.hosts[message.nodeId]);
              out.writeObject(replyMessage);
            }
        }

        if (message.type.trim().equals("REPLY")) {
          // do something 
        }

      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
```

I run this code on two machines. The connections are established successfully and some messages are exchanged. However, in some cases the Processor class does not get message even when the socket is still connected.

I did go through some questions on missing messages with Java sockets which mentioned that when nodes gets two messages at once, it processes only the first message and the second message is buffered. I am not sure how I can check if that is the case with my code.

I am guessing something is wrong with I am handling sockets. Would really help if anyone could point where I am doing things incorrectly.

TIA

Comment: I suspect you need to flush() the ObjectOutputStream after writing.

Comment: Note also that although you *can* perform IPC with Object streams, it is rarely desirable to do so.  You do gain a certain code simplicity, but you pay for it with bandwidth bloat and at least two separate kinds of implementation- and version-dependency.  It's easy to accidentally leak data that way, too.

Comment: I tried out.flush(), no change in the code execution. :( @Joe

Comment: @JohnBollinger , I am sorry I did not follow what you meant. Socket Programming terms are slightly new to me.

Comment: @maddie, it has nothing specifically to do with sockets, really.  Sending a whole object over an Object stream involves transmitting more -- sometimes *much* more -- data than you really need to convey, and if you're not careful then some of that data may be stuff you did not want to expose.  Moreover, it only works if both sides are implemented in Java, and the whole thing can break if there is version skew between the classes on one side and the other.  That applies just as much if you write the data to a file for later readback as if you send them over the network.

Comment: So, in my case, both sides are written in Java. Infact, it is the same code running on every Node. But, what is the fix to make sure no data is lost when sending a whole object? Thanks @JohnBollinger